# RxJava Observable from iterable that need to be generated in background

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I want to have an Observable from iterable that returns segment of a list each time but the problem is I need that list to be generated asynchronously form another observable, how can I do that?

```java
Observable.fromIterable(getListAsync())
        .buffer(3, 3) 
        .subscribe()
```

Comment: `someSource.getAsyncData().flatMapIterable { .. }`

Answer (score 0):

After some searching what I did is

```java
private Observable<List<Object>> generateListObservable() {
    return Single.create(emitter -> {
        ArrayList<Integer> aInteger = new ArrayList<>();
        aInteger.add(1);
        aInteger.add(2);
        aInteger.add(3);
        aInteger.add(4);
        aInteger.add(5);
        aInteger.add(6);
        emitter.onSuccess(aInteger);
    }).flattenAsObservable(o -> (Iterable<? extends List<Object>>) o);
}
```

After that I have an Observable that i can combine with other methods; here I used Zip return a list of 2 elements at a time with 1 second delay between each one

```java
private void displayListInChunks(){
    Observable.zip(generateListObservable().buffer(2),
            Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
            (o, aLong) -> o).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(lists ->
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, lists.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());    
}
```